# AppStoreConnect: There are one or more errors on the page - no error highlighted

Tags: ios, build, account, app-store-connect

[image]This is driving me insane. It doesn't highlight where the issue is. Never had this problem before. It started a few days ago, I had published hundreds of apps previously.

App name: OK

Privacy Policy: OK

Category: OK

Bundle ID: OK

Price: OK (set to free)

Screenshots OK (I checked in Media Manager as well)

Description: OK

Keywords: OK

Support URL: OK

Build: OK (processed and selected)

Age Rating: OK

Copyright: OK

Contact info: OK

These were the mandatory things a few days ago. Now I get an error while doesn't saying where the error is! I cleaned the cookies and cache, didn't help. Perhaps you guys can help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, be sure to put your code and error messages directly in your answer, linking out is unadvised.

Comment: If your app is localized to other app stores, the problem may lie in one of those, so it does not appear on your default page.

Comment: @CodeBender is correct. Check your other localizations/languages.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no errors and it just says, `"There are one or more errors on page"`

the following can be a solution.

Click on the "Pricing" tab

and choose `Price Tier` as `Free` or `your price`

and go to your app again and Submit, Cheers.

Also, check other tabs.

Comment: You should inspect the response from the apple server. The response contains a JSON. Search for "errorKeys", where it is not null or []. This way, you can find out the exact problem.

In my case it was saying "You must choose a version release option.", basically I needed to checkoff the pre-order option to expose the UI to select "Manually Release" option. After I selected that option, I checked back the pre-order option. This resolved the problem